# App crashes when opening a ftp link in browser, with Device.OpenUri(uri), in Xamarin

Tags: android, url, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, ftp

I'm currently implementing a part of Xamarin app, which needs to open links in browser, after clicking the URL. I need to add support for http, https, ftp and ftps.
Our app uses .NET Standard 1.6 (Thus, can't use WebClient Class or FtpWebRequest class).

Device.OpenUri(uri) works fine with http and https in both iOS and Android. But only works with iOS for ftp links. With Android, app crashes with ftp links.

For **file links with ftp**, I managed to download files using FluentFTP (version="23.1.0").

Now I need to add support for **ftp links with directory structures**, to open that directory structure in the browser. (Like the default behavior of the Chrome browser)

I have tried:

- Device.OpenUri(uri),
- By creating an intent (Not working for ftp)

Comment: Post your code and crash log please

Answer (score 0):

What you should be doing is something like below:

- Create an interface for your Dependency Service for Android.

  ```
  public interface IWebFTPClient<T>
  {
      Task<T> MakeFtpRequestAsync(); //Add Parameters if needed
  }
  ```
- Then call the depedency service method :

  ```
  DependencyService.Get<IWebFTPClient<YourType>>().MakeFtpRequestAsync();
  ```

Note: Above code is an example piece and may need changes as per your needs

- Since [FtpWebRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/System.Net.FtpWebRequest?view=netframework-4.7.2) is available in native android, use it something like follows:

  ```
  FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(serverUri);
  ```

Good luck

Revert if you have queries